# Why the throwed object is going to the oppesite direction?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement (throwing objects) feature, but sometimes it has weird behaviour. Objects should be thrown in the direction of the camera(forward). but sometimes objects are thrown the opposite way (to the player). I don't know why this is happening?

```
 if (heldObj != null) //if player is holding object
        {
            MoveObject(); //keep object position at holdPos
           // RotateObject();
            if (Throw && canDrop == true) //Mous0 (leftclick) is used to throw, change this if you want another button to be used)
            {
                StopClipping();
                ThrowObject();
            }
            Throw = false;
        
        }
void ThrowObject()
    {
        //same as drop function, but add force to object before undefining it
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(heldObj.GetComponent<Collider>(), player.GetComponent<Collider>(), false);
        heldObj.layer = 0;
        heldObjRb.isKinematic = false;
        heldObj.transform.parent = null;
        Vector3 camerDirection = camera.transform.forward;
        heldObjRb.AddForce(camerDirection * throwForce);
      //  heldObjRb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None; 
        heldObj = null;
        reticle.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.75f);
        reticle.enabled = true;
    }
   private void PickUpObject(GameObject pickUpObj)
    {
        if (pickUpObj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>()) { 
            reticle.enabled = false;
            heldObj = pickUpObj; 
            heldObjRb = pickUpObj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); 
            heldObjRb.isKinematic = true;
            heldObjRb.transform.parent = holdPos.transform; 
            heldObj.layer = LayerNumber;                              
            Physics.IgnoreCollision(heldObj.GetComponent<Collider>(), player.GetComponent<Collider>(), true);
            reticle.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.75f);
            
        }
    }
```

How can fix this?
Note: it doesn't happen always but sometimes only. most of the time the object is thrown to the direction of the camera (all objects have colliders and rigidbody)

Answer (score 0):

You do not ingore collisions between object and player, so depending on the point you throw the object from, it can occasionally collide with the player and thus have enexpected behavior. Also, I would recommend to have separate transform(and make it a child of player) which you take forward vector from, not camera's. You will have more control that way.

Comment: I ignored the collision between player and object on the PickUp() method. isn't that enough? can you please check again? I added this function so you can see

Comment: You add the collision back in your throw method `Physics.IgnoreCollision(heldObj.GetComponent<Collider>(), player.GetComponent<Collider>(), false);
` ... you could add a little delay for that